# When Text is bigger at that time text is Cuts off?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-screen-support, android-layout-weight

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listitem_contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="abcdefghijklm, Miss abcdefghi"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_map"
            android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_color"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_textmessage"
            android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_color"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
            android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_color"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

here when text is abcdefghijklm, Miss abcdefghi in Textview at that time Text cutssOff I am only using LinearLayout.

Can anybody help me where I need to do changes?

Comment: Remove the `android:layout_weight` and check.

Comment: yes but for all screens it's not working like Tablet & all devices..

Comment: Would you mind showing screenshots of how it has to be and what is happening now?

Comment: i don't have 10 reputations so could not attached the document.

Comment: Post it somewhere else and give the link here.

Comment: you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/5296734) out, may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try vertical orientation and wrap_content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listitem_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="14dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="14dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="abcdefghijklm, Miss abcdefghi"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_color"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_textmessage"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_color"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_color"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is a row of the Listview and not possible layout_width ="wrap_content"and weight = 1 and this must to be in the horizonatl

Comment: Anyone pls help me out how will I proceed for this Layout ?

Comment: can you post image of view you want to have.

Comment: I dont't have the 10 points so can not upload the image sorry